# Apache, mod_rewrite. Simple and proven RewriteRule doesn't work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, localhost

The dynamic URL: **`http://localhost/?langName=spa`**

The rewritten URL: **`http://localhost/spa`**

Here is **full content** of **.htaccess**:

```
DirectoryIndex ed.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule //(.*)/(.*)/$ /?$1=$2
</IfModule>
```

**Result:**

**`The requested URL /spa was not found on this server.`**

*`Apache/2.0.59 (Win32) PHP/5.2.3 Server at localhost Port 80`*

Please, where is error?
Thanks!

Comment: This RewriteRule should transform rewritten URL (`http://localhost/spa`) by dynamic URL (`http://localhost/?langName=spa`). The sample is from  [RewriteRule Generator](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3FlangName%3Dspa&style=1&page_name=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspa)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work :

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} langName=([a-z]+)
RewriteRule ^$ %1
```

Comment: RewriteRule must transform rewritten URL by dynamic URL.

Comment: Result is the same. This RewriteRule should transform rewritten URL (`http://localhost/spa`) by dynamic URL (`http://localhost/?langName=spa`)